# How to make Responsive Text

Tags: javascript, css

I have an example [Calendar Days](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasAJ/0eeb3j5e/1/)

```css
.month-days-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.day-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.day-header {
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
  height: 26px;
}

.day-weekday {
  background-color: #ededee;
}

.day-weekend {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.day-body {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
  height: 50px;
}

.end-ellipsis {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="month-days-wrapper">

    
<div class="day-wrapper">
<div class="day-header day-weekday">We</div>
<div class="day-body">
<div class="day-body-day">25</div>
<div style="z-index: 1; position: relative; left: 21px; top: 5px; width: 174px; height: 20px; background-color: green; border-radius: 5px" onmouseout="hidePopup();" onmousemove="showPopup(event, this, 'Owner', 'Booking', '0', '0');">
<div class="end-ellipsis">Tom Jones - $4,000</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="day-wrapper">
<div class="day-header day-weekday">Th</div>
<div class="day-body">
<div class="day-body-day">26</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="day-wrapper">
<div class="day-header day-weekday">Fr</div>
<div class="day-body">
<div class="day-body-day">27</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="day-wrapper">
<div class="day-header day-weekend">Sa</div>
<div class="day-body">
<div class="day-body-day">28</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="day-wrapper">
<div class="day-header day-weekend">Su</div>
<div class="day-body">
<div class="day-body-day">29</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="day-wrapper">
<div class="day-header day-weekday">Mo</div>
<div class="day-body">
<div class="day-body-day">30</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Squeeze the Result horizontally and you will see the days are responsive.
(Totally ignore the green line please as that will be taken care of by server side coding.)

The challenge is to make the text “Tom Jones – $4,000” responsive also.

Can this be done via CSS and maybe JS as well?

Edit
Please have a look at this image as it will hopefully explain what I am getting at clearly.

[More Detailed Image http://d29u7d0naxols0.cloudfront.net/TextFlowsWithDays.jpg](http://d29u7d0naxols0.cloudfront.net/TextFlowsWithDays.jpg)

More edit.

Background: This is a monthly line calendar for a booking app whose days move to the second row, third row, etc when its container is narrowed. This works perfectly well.

12 months-at-a-time are shown on the web page.

When a property is booked the calendar needs to show the Name and $Amount starting *ON THE FIRST DAY* of the booking.
When the calendar is narrowed and a day goes to the following row the text must track the day as shown in the image above.

**Boundary Conditions**

1. A booking may be one night or 100s of nights.
2. If a short booking and all text cannot be fitted in then finish it with ellipsis.
3. The text must flow across month boundaries. eg booking starts on Nov 30 so text must flow to Dec 1 etc

If anyone can do this then I will pay an agreed amount otherwise I will go to Freelancer.com. (I am offering the $s here as people have made an effort already and should be rewarded if they can "bring home the goods".)

Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a site for soliciting paid work.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need js, you can use scalable values for your text on font-size

vh is the percentage of the height
`font-size:2vh`

vw is the percentage of the width
`font-size:2vw`

vmin is the percentage of the shorter one  (useful for mobile)
`font-size:2vmin`

vmax is the percentage of the longer one
`font-size:2vmax`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Sorry but vh/vw is not what I am after. Perhaps I did not explain myself well - maybe the headline could have been better but there are limits.

If you look at the jsfiddle, the days stack when Result is narrowed. I want the text to follow the stacked day/s . I do not want the text to resize.

Comment: In the following image I need the '$4,000' to start over 'Sa 28'.

![Text is wrong](http://d29u7d0naxols0.cloudfront.net/Textiswrong.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to get a feel for exactly what you're going for here, but here are a couple of thoughts.

In your original code, the green background booking info is part of the div for the day on which it starts. As long as you do things this way, it will never scale properly when you adjust the screen size.

With that in mind, here is a modified code which moves the booking info to the end of the date container, which will keep it there as you resize the page.

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="month-days-wrapper">
        <div class="day-wrapper">
            <div class="day-header day-weekday">We
            </div>
            <div class="day-body">
                <div class="day-body-day">25
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day-wrapper">
            <div class="day-header day-weekday">Th
            </div>
            <div class="day-body">
                <div class="day-body-day">26
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day-wrapper">
            <div class="day-header day-weekday">Fr
            </div>
            <div class="day-body">
                <div class="day-body-day">27
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day-wrapper">
        <div class="day-header day-weekend">Sa
        </div>
            <div class="day-body">
                <div class="day-body-day">28
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day-wrapper">
            <div class="day-header day-weekend">Su
            </div>
            <div class="day-body">
                <div class="day-body-day">29
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day-wrapper">
            <div class="day-header day-weekday">Mo
            </div>
            <div class="day-body">
                <div class="day-body-day">30
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class='text-container' onmouseout="hidePopup();" onmousemove="showPopup(event, this, 'Owner', 'Booking', '0', '0');">
        <div class="end-ellipsis">Tom Jones - $4,000
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


.month-days-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.day-wrapper {
  float: left;
}
```

and the CSS:

```
.day-header {
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
  height: 26px;
}

.day-weekday {
  background-color: #ededee;
}

.day-weekend {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.day-body {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
  height: 50px;
}

.end-ellipsis {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.text-container {
    z-index: 10; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px; 
    bottom: 5px; 
    width: 174px; 
    height: 20px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -87px;
    background-color: green; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

However, as a related point, is this is part of a larger application (looks like it might be related to some kind of booking system), you might want to consider dynamically setting the background colors of the date divs rather than putting this overlay on them. It will be much less finicky. Just a thought.

Good luck, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Sorry knolljm but no good. (yes a booking system)
1. Yes the text "Tom Jones etc" moves to the last day but not what I am after.
2. Cannot set BG color for booked dates because 1 day can have a check-out and a check-in. But please, everyone, ignore the green. It is under control easily via C# on the server.

PLEASE everyone have a look at my jsfiddle AND my image in my comment to the FIRST reply. The image clearly shows that the text is spilling outside the first line of days. I want it to follow onto the second line of days.

Comment: I strongly suspect it cannot be done by CSS alone but needs some clever JS.

Anyway if anyone can work it out please PM me and I will pay.

Answer (score 0):

A little tricky, but I think this is what you need [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/nsbp1y3n/3/)
Splitted the word in multiple containers and gave them `display:inline-block`

Comment: Sorry, not what I am after.

I have edited my original question with a new image that will hopefully explain clearly what I am after.

Comment: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/nsbp1y3n/3/) Almost, right? I splitted the word in multiple containers

Comment: Yes indeed "Almost right". But the letters sometimes still go beyond the end of the last day of the first row.
But still impressive. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, just adjust the letter-spacing and the left/top position of the main div "word-cont". And you still need a little js to generate the containers and to adjust this values dinamically, checking the length.

Comment: Thanks Gioele for your efforts but I don't think a little bit extra here and there will solve this riddle. If you think you can do a professional job taking into account boundary conditions (see my edit to the OP) then I will be happy to pay you. Or anyone else for that matter. Otherwise I will put it up on Freelancer.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cold try a trick with `line-height`, then use an extra span container (or child div itself), `position:absolute` and `word-wrap`/`word-break` :

*`.end-ellipsis` class is removed.*

remove test `width` from `.month-days-wrapper` to test on resize or play with http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYBypL .

```css
.month-days-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.day-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.day-header {
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
  height: 26px;
}

.day-weekday {
  background-color: #ededee;
}

.day-weekend {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.day-body {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
  height: 50px;
}

.end-ellipsis {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.brlines {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -1.6em;
  text-indent: 1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all
}

.brlines span {
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  line-height: 5em;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="month-days-wrapper">
  <div class="day-wrapper">
    <div class="day-header day-weekday">We</div>
    <div class="day-body">
      <div class="day-body-day">25</div>
      <div class="brlines">
        <div onmouseout="hidePopup();" onmousemove="showPopup(event, this, 'Owner', 'Booking', '0', '0');"><span>Tom Jones - $4,000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-wrapper">
    <div class="day-header day-weekday">Th</div>
    <div class="day-body">
      <div class="day-body-day">26</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-wrapper">
    <div class="day-header day-weekday">Fr</div>
    <div class="day-body">
      <div class="day-body-day">27</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-wrapper">
    <div class="day-header day-weekend">Sa</div>
    <div class="day-body">
      <div class="day-body-day">28</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-wrapper">
    <div class="day-header day-weekend">Su</div>
    <div class="day-body">
      <div class="day-body-day">29</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-wrapper">
    <div class="day-header day-weekday">Mo</div>
    <div class="day-body">
      <div class="day-body-day">30</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```